# Generating an infinite sequence in Haskell

Tags: haskell, infinite-sequence

I know that infinite sequences are possible in Haskell - however, I'm not entirely sure how to generate one

Given a method

```
generate::Integer->Integer
```

which take an integer and produces the next integer in the sequence, how would I build an infinite sequence out of this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want your sequence to start from 1 then it is -

```
iterate generate 1
```

Please notice that first letter of function is lowercase, not uppercase. Otherwise it would be data type, not function.

//edit: I just realized not just data types start with capital, it could be data constructor or type class as well, but that wasn't the point. :)

Answer (score 13):

Adding to Matajon's answer: a way to discover the `iterate` function other than asking here would be to use Hoogle.

[Hoogle's first answer for the query](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%28a+-%3E+a%29+-%3E+%5Ba%5D) `(a -> a) -> [a]` is `iterate`.

**Update (2023):** Hoogle's scoring appears to have changed and `iterate` is no longer given with this query. It's full type has another `a` parameter and with the full type it is given in the results.

Comment: I'm confused. iterate is not in Hoogle's list now. I just clicked on the link and I couldn't find it. What do I miss here?

Comment: @ArpadHorvath--СлаваУкраїні It appears than since 2009 Hoogle's scoring function changed.
The full type for iterate has an additional "a -> " and with that query it does give iterate as of now.

Answer (score 7):

There are several ways to do it, but one is:

```
gen :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
gen f s = s : gen f (f s)
```

This function takes a functon `f` and some valus `s` and returns `s`, after wich it calls itself with that same `f`, and the result of `f s`. Demonstration:

```
Prelude> :t succ
succ :: (Enum a) => a -> a
Prelude> let gen f s = s : gen f (f s)
Prelude> take 10 $ gen succ 3
[3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

In the above example `succ` acts as the function `generate :: Integer -> Integer` which you mention. But observe that `gen` will work with any function of type `a -> a`.

**Edit:** and indeed, `gen` is identical to the function [`iterate`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html#v%3Aiterate) from the Prelude (and Data.List).